# ANGULARJS: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:62259/Service1.svc/getAllUsers. Invalid HTTP status code 405"

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, http-status-code-405, http-options-method

So, this is the situation:

1. I am developing a web app with AngularJS (client-side) and C# (server-side);
2. I have already some web services running well, with no problems (gelAllUsers, getOrderDetails, etc etc);
3. After I implement the authentication code, the web services stop working. Here are the errors messages:

   - OPTIONS http://localhost:62259/Service1.svc/getAllUsers
   - XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:62259/Service1.svc/getAllUsers. Invalid HTTP status code 405
4. I realized then that the problem is due to every code lines with "$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = ..."
5. After some search, I know I may need to do something which allows the Authorization header.

But what? And how?And where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, and it works thanks to an article in CodeProject.
As I am novice in web developing, here is the detailed procedure I had to follow in order to perform it successfully:

1. Understand why this problem exists and that all is needed is to enable CORS in WCF:

   - Read carefully the article in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/845474/Enabling-CORS-in-WCF

     - Believe me, it's worth it. I wouldn't explain better;
2. As I am using Visual Studio to develop my WCF Web Services, in order to create the file Global.asax, I had to:
       * In Solution Explorer, right-click in the project name -> Add -> New Item...
       * in the left menu, Web -> General and the select Global Application Class
       * write this code:

   protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost");
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, DELETE");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

}

3. Note that, in this case, it is needed to add 'Authorization' in

   HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
4. delete similar stuff you might have in web.config or else you will have a conflict due to redundant data.

I thing I said everything.